# ¿Cuál es el origen de "cacerolazo"?

Tags: etimología, argentina, chile, venezuela

En septiembre del año pasado:

> El mandatario venezolano, Nicolás Maduro fue recibido ***a golpes de ollas*** y gritos de protesta por los vecinos del barrio Villa Rosa, ubicado en Isla Margarita, cuando se disponía a realizar un acto político durante la noche de este viernes.
>   [- El Heraldo](https://www.elheraldo.co/mundo/nicolas-maduro-huye-de-cacerolazo-en-isla-margarita-282778)

Este tipo de protesta es tipificada como ***cacerolazo*** (también cacerolada):

> Protesta colectiva en la que se hace ruido con cacerolas
>   [- DRAE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=6UzQDKE)

Según mis búsquedas, solo tiene significado como protesta desde la época de Pinochet, pero aparece en [ngrams en un libro de “Chilenismos](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22cacerolada%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1770,cd_max:1943&lr=lang_es)”  en 1900. ¿Cuándo fue que la palabra empezó a tener significado de protesta?

Comment: La historia de los cacerolazos está (creo que bien) explicada [en Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cacerolazo), pero no se dan detalles sobre la palabra en sí. Siendo argentino la recuerdo como un neologismo en los '90, pero en esa época no teníamos, como hoy, muchos medios para chequear si eso que era novedad para nosotros ya era conocido con ese mismo nombre en otros países...

Comment: Estoy también interesado en saber si tal vez hay algún vínculo entre "cacerolazo" y la frase _tin-pot dictator_ en Inglés.

Comment: Por lo que veo en wikipedia sobre tin-pot dictator esto hace referencia a tin-pot como un utensilio "barato" o de poco valor y la frase se remonta a la época del "Imperio Británico" mientras que cacerolazo es una protesta donde se usan cacerolas y demás utensilios de cocina para hacer ruido, sin importar cual sea la calidad del personaje contra el cual se protesta.

Answer (score 3):

La "cacerolada" que Ud. ligó del año 1900 describe la comida que llena una cacerola.

La Francia ha tenido "[casserolades](http://www.liberation.fr/france/2017/09/25/d-ou-viennent-les-concerts-de-casseroles_1598726)" desde hace muchos años. En español, el "cacerolazo" ha sido una manifestación,  por lo menos desde "[La marcha de las cacerolas vacías](http://www.memoriachilena.cl/602/w3-article-100709.html)" contra Allende, en Chile, 1971. En esta foto se nota que fueron pocas ollas que se alzaron.

[image: La protesta]

Answer (score 2):

Por mi conocimiento personal te puedo decir que la primera protesta chilena en la que se golpearon cacerolas fue en contra del presidente Salvador Allende, la noche del 1° de diciembre de 1971, aprovechando la visita que hizo a Chile el líder cubano Fidel Castro. Se dice que "la noche de las ollas" fue una acción espontánea de parte de las mujeres de la burguesía media-alta (ya se había escuchado golpes de ollas esporádicos algunos días antes, lo que sugiere este origen espontáneo), pero lo más probable es que haya sido organizada por la derecha política, que estaba muy motivada en esa época, por medio del movimiento "Poder Femenino".

Como fuera, estaban imitando una protesta famosa que le habían hecho al mismo Castro en Cuba muchos años antes, también golpeando ollas vacías. Esto ocurrió en la ciudad de Cárdenas en 1962 y es conocido como "la protesta de los calderos" o algo así. Por lo tanto, si buscas el origen del *cacerolazo* como símbolo, puedes mirar por ese lado.

Pero si lo que buscas es el origen de la palabra "*cacerolazo*", ésta tiene que haber surgido en el registro popular chileno después de este evento de 1971 y antes de 1974, que es cuando ya se puede encontrar la palabra [en letra impresa](https://books.google.cl/books?id=w3zjAAAAMAAJ&q=%22cacerolazo%22&dq=%22cacerolazo%22&hl=es-419&sa=X&redir_esc=y).

Durante este tiempo el golpe de ollas no fue tanto símbolo de escasez ("ollas vacías") como de la oposición al modelo socialista, lo cual fue claramente entendido por Fidel Castro. (*¡Fidel a la olla / aliñado con cebolla!*). Diez años después, en los 80, las cacerolas se dieron vuelta, ahora en contra de la derecha partidaria de Pinochet. Los mismos que antes caceroleaban, ahora eran los que recibían el cacerolazo (imagínate cuán indignadas habrán estado esas señoras).

Tus descubrimientos de principios del siglo XX, yo estimo que se refieren a "golpes dados con una cacerola" contra algo o alguien, sin ánimo de protesta.

Answer (score 2):

El sufijo **-ada** tiene, entre otros, los siguientes usos:

> [**-ada**](http://dle.rae.es/srv/fetch?id=0gYeQoM)
>      1. suf. Forma sustantivos derivados de otros sustantivos que significan conjunto. *Fritada, vacada.*
>      4. suf. Forma sustantivos derivados de otros sustantivos que indican golpe. *Palmada, pedrada.*

Se deduce entonces que "cacerolada" es una forma de referirse tanto a que en la manifestación había un conjunto de cacerolas, como al hecho de que las estaban golpeando (para hacer ruido).

Particularmente nunca habia visto referirse a este tipo de actos como "cacerol**azo**", pero tambien es válido:

> [**-azo, za**](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=-azo)
>   5. suf. A veces significa golpe dado con lo designado por la base derivativa. *Porrazo, almohadillazo.*
>   6. suf. En algún caso, señala el golpe dado en lo significado por la base derivativa. *Espaldarazo.*

Answer (score 1):

A lo dicho sobre el uso de la palabra con la terminación "azo" (por golpe, como *bastonazo*, aquel que se da con un bastón) hay que notar que —como bien recoge el diccionario de la RAE—, el término se refiere a una protesta política, con un sentido de manifestación popular hecha demanda y movilizacion colectiva. Existen en la historia latinoamericana varias revueltas populares también nombradas con el subfijo de "golpe" (algunas famosas a fines de los 60 en Argentina como el "[Tucumanazo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tucumanazo)", o el "[Cordobazo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cordobazo)").

La denominación "cacerolazo", que transmite bien el sentido de protesta social por el ahogo de una precariedad económica esencial (con cacerolas golpeadas cual campanas de hambre) se asocia por tanto fuertemente a manifestaciones pacíficas pero intensas, "puebladas insurreccionales" ('civil uprising').

Sobre el origen del término, encontré esta referencia en un [diccionario de la política chilena](https://books.google.com.ar/books?id=rOpQcfVvo_EC&pg=PT37&dq=cacerolazo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiIt8Of0bfkAhUuHLkGHYgXAzA4HhDoAQgtMAE), que consigna antecedentes posteriores, en las décadas del 70 y 80 que hicieron conocido su uso en Chile. La publicación da cuenta de una manifestación de mujeres en 1971 en contra de la visita de Fidel Castro, —contrariando en parte el sentido humilde de las protestantes a quienes un jingle radical denunciaba como apócrifas sufrientes diciendo "*esa olla es nueva-eva, vieja mentirosa-osa*"—, más otra protesta de caracter nacional contra el régimen dictatorial vigente entonces, —acompañada por el jingle "*a puro pan, a puro te, así nos tiene Pinochet*".

Respecto a la pregunta sobre la relación del término con la expresión *tinpot-dictator*, más allá de la referencia común al mismo elemento de cocina (pot = cacerola), no parece haber conexión con la frase anglosajona (que alude al descrédito político de una autoridad auto-impuesta y detentanto un mando político sin respaldo ni valoración; alguien carente de legitimidad que, cual instrumento de escasa calidad, es menospreciado en su rol gobernante, sea por fragilidad o por su evidente dependencia, títere [puppet] de otros factores de poder).

Comment: @walen, si el mio al ser más una acotación que una respuesta debiera haber ido como un comentario. Voy a ampliarla para intentar contestar lo que la pregunta intenta saber. ¡Gracias!