# En la frase "Caceroladas y concentraciones de apoyo al Rey", ¿hay ambigüedad sobre si la primera parte es afectada por "de apoyo al Rey"?

Tags: significado, conjunciones, interpretación

El domingo 25 de febrero el rey de España estuvo en Barcelona. Por una [serie de motivos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categor%C3%ADa:Proceso_soberanista_de_Catalu%C3%B1a_de_2012-2017), una parte de la población no lo considera bienvenido en la ciudad, por lo que organizaron una cacerolada para *acompañar* su paso por las calles de camino a un evento. En paralelo, otra gente (menos) se manifestó para mostrar su apoyo al monarca. Ved [la noticia](http://www.lavanguardia.com/politica/20180225/441070874850/tension-centro-barcelona-coincidir-concentraciones-tabarnia-cdr.html), si bien es algo tangencial.

La cuestión es que el contexto necesario se resume en:

- hubo un [*cacerolazo*](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/20954/1674) en contra
- hubo alguna manifestación a favor

Más tarde por Twitter circuló una captura de pantalla de una emisión en directo de una televisión, donde se leía:

> [image]
>
> Ante el comienzo del Mobile World Congress. Caceroladas y concentraciones de apoyo al Rey.

La parte a favor de la cacerolada [se indignó](https://twitter.com/Xavi_Penela/status/967890968698646532), pues entendía esta frase como una forma de englobar tanto las caceroladas como las concentraciones en manifestaciones de apoyo al Rey. Para muchos, era como si escribieran:

> (Caceroladas y concentraciones) de apoyo al Rey.

Cuando a todas luces el significado real (:P) debería ser:

> (Caceroladas) y (concentraciones de apoyo al Rey).

A mí, por contra, me parece que, aun siendo ambigua, la frase puede entenderse de las dos formas y el contexto es suficientemente explícito como para que la gente entienda que la cacerolada tiene una componente negativa. Eso sí, para reducir la ambigüedad probablemente lo suyo sería separar físicamente las dos partes e indicar:

> (Concentraciones de apoyo al Rey) y (caceroladas).

Mi duda pues, es: ¿es gramáticalmente correcta la conjunción de elementos, cuando el segundo es el único que arrastra la parte *de apoyo al Rey*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si te digo que en una caja tengo guardados "calzado y ropa de verano", podrías entender que "de verano" aplica tanto al calzado como a la ropa.
Si en cambio te digo que en esa caja tengo guardados "bufandas y ropa de verano", seguramente entenderías que "de verano" aplica solo a la ropa, porque *lo normal* es que las bufandas sean de invierno.

Si te digo "insultos y aplausos a favor de Griezmann", habría que ser un poco retorcido para interpretar que los insultos son *a favor* de Griezmann.

Creo que el caso que presentas es similar: lo normal es que una "cacerolada" se haga en contra de algo o como protesta por algo. No tengo noticia de caceroladas "a favor de" o "de apoyo a" de nada. Por tanto, en "caceroladas y concentraciones de apoyo al Rey" lo normal sería interpretar que tenemos caceroladas por un lado (en contra) y concentraciones de apoyo por otro (a favor).

Gramaticalmente hablando, ¿se podría interpretar que "de apoyo al Rey" aplica a ambos elementos? Sí, claro que se podría, pero estaríamos ignorando el contexto y [violando las reglas del método comunicacional](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/26511/13628) establecido.

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta sobre la corrección gramática está bien hecha por @walen. 
Pero **destaco la pregunta de @fiedorqui por cuanto pone acento en el celo necesario ante los mensajes mediáticos** que lateralmente editorializan o sesgan, como podría ocurrir acaso con una comprensión ambigua, como en este caso.

**La susceptibilidad de los barceloneses organizadores de la cacerolada** —que aunque siempre es una protesta, también [registra antecedentes como manifestación de derecha](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/20954/cu%C3%A1l-es-el-origen-de-cacerolazo)— **se halla por eso muy justificada**, sabedores de que en el ágora mediática se usan armas sofisticadas, haciendo un fino equilibrio en el filo de la pertinencia gramatical.