# ¿Por qué decimos «¿Te importa si...?» para pedir permiso?

Tags: expresiones, significado, cortesía

Cuando se está con otra(s) persona(s) y se quiere pedir su aprobación para hacer algo que quizá podría importunarla(s), una fórmula habitual para ello es lanzar la siguiente pregunta:

> ***¿Te importa / Os importa si...?***

Seguido de la acción que queremos llevar a cabo:

> ¿Os importa si abro la ventana?
>   ¿Te importa si invito a Juan?
>   ¿Os importa si cojo la última aceituna?*
>   <sub><sub>*No recomendado si valoras tu estatus social. La última aceituna nunca se coge.</sub></sub>

Ante lo cual, las posibles respuestas son básicamente dos:

- *«**No** me / **No** nos importa»*, lo cual quiere decir que **sí** les parece bien que haga lo indicado.
- *«**Sí** me / **Sí** nos importa»*, lo cual quiere decir que **no** les parece bien.

Sin embargo, el otro día mi señora se levantó con el ánimo pícaro, y la siguiente conversación tuvo lugar entre ella y yo:

> —Estoy asado, ¿os importa si me quito la camiseta?
>   —Sí me importa, mucho.
>   —Ah, vale. Pues nada, no me la quito.
>   —No, quítatela.
>   —Pero si me has dicho que...
>   —Te he dicho que me importa. De hecho es muy importante para mí que te la quites :-) Así que ¡venga!

Mi reacción fue más o menos [esta](https://media.giphy.com/media/2pHCxQtUttmHm/giphy.gif).
Y es que, pensándolo bien... Si a alguien no le importa algo, podemos suponer que no tiene problema en que lo hagamos, pero **¿en qué nos basamos para interpretar que "sí me importa" es un rechazo?** ¿Cuál es el significado de [***importar***](http://dle.rae.es/?id=L5Z4xUK) que estamos aplicando al hacer la pregunta? ¿Hay algún otro argumento, más allá de que sea la convención establecida?

Comment: Me sumo a la reacción ilustrada por el GIF.

Comment: Yo tomaría "importa" en tu pregunta como un eufemismo aceptable de "molesta".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Da lo mismo lo que "importar" signifique. Es solo una marca pragmática que usamos para evitar decir las cosas directamente.

Cuando dices *¿te importa si abro la ventana?* estás recurriendo a un método comunicacional basado en la "cortesía". No es la cortesía *social* de los buenos modales, sino una cortesía *lingüística* que consiste en expandir el mensaje agregando "pistas" que den a entender al interlocutor que él es importante, y que él es quien va a tomar las decisiones con respecto a lo que yo quiero hacer con las palabras. Yo quiero abrir la ventana pero eres tú la persona que va a tomar finalmente la decisión. Pero... esto es una actuación, porque en realidad no me importa que a ti te importe, y tú sabes que para mí no es importante que te importe, ni te importa que no me importe.

Lo curioso es que en realidad no es equivalente a la cortesía social. De hecho, cuando hablas con tu señora sobre la camiseta, en realidad sí te importa, y a ella también, y van a llegar a un acuerdo cordial. Pero *la forma en que lo dices* es una tecnología mental, un script. La expansión aparentemente innecesaria del mensaje (*te importaría, serías tan amable, si no fuera mucha molestia, sería posible que, solo quiero pedirte que, siento molestarte pero*) mantiene una atmósfera de equilibrio durante la comunicación. (Esto ha sido estudiado por la pragmalingüística desde los años 70 y luego se ha abordado también desde una perspectiva cognitiva y evolucionista).

Nos guste o no, la hipocresía lingüística es un rasgo universal humano, y no es propia solo de los políticos ni de los vendedores, sino de todo el mundo, con algunas menores diferencias culturales. Cada vez que hablamos somos vagos, exagerados, usamos dobles sentidos, nos vamos por las ramas y esperamos que nuestros interlocutores también lo hagan.

*¿Puedes pasarme la salsa?* significa "dame la salsa", independiente de que el interlocutor "pueda pasarla" o "no pueda pasarla". Y aunque estemos en un ambiente de absoluta confianza, totalmente seguros de nuestro estatus y del tipo de relación que tenemos con el otro, no nos gusta que nos ordenen "dame la salsa". Queremos (de hecho *necesitamos*) que nos pregunten *¿me pasarías la salsa?, ¿serías tan amable de pasarme la salsa?, ¿tienes salsa...?, ¿está la salsa ahí porfa?*

Las inferencias pragmáticas son automáticas, y forman parte del lenguaje en un  nivel profundo. Romper intencionalmente las reglas de cortesía y otras similares, es uno de los métodos típicos del humorismo, y por eso tú y tu señora se rieron. De otro modo, podríamos pensar que ella es pedante o que tiene Síndrome de Asperger.

Answer (score 2):

Es curioso que la última acepción de la palabra sea [la siguiente](http://dle.rae.es/?id=L5Z4xUK):

> 6. intr. Convenir, interesar, afectar profundamente, ser de mucha entidad o consecuencia.

Da la sensación de que todos estos significados no se pueden dar a la vez, y sin embargo entre ellos encontramos el que nos conviene e interesa (juego de palabras intencionado). Fíjate qué diferencia si sustituimos el verbo *importar* en el primer ejemplo, suponiendo que la respuesta es que "puedes abrir la ventana", por cada una de las partes de la citada acepción:

> ¿Os conviene que abra la ventana? `Sí, nos conviene, ábrela`.
>   ¿Os interesa que abra la ventana? `Sí, nos interesa, ábrela`.
>   ¿Os [afecta](http://dle.rae.es/?id=0wAWT95) (perjudica) profundamente que abra la ventana? `No, no nos afecta, ábrela`.
>   ¿Es algo de mucha [entidad](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Fi7uEzC) (importancia) para vosotros el que abra la ventana? `(Provoca respuesta ambigua nuevamente.)`
>   ¿Tendrá consecuencias el que abra la ventana? `(Ambigua: ¿Buenas o malas?)`

Y todo forma parte de la misma acepción. Lo habitual es que la respuesta se haga atendiendo a uno de los significados de respuesta negativa:

> ¿Os afecta (perjudica) profundamente que me quite la camiseta? `No, no nos afecta, quítatela`.

En cambio tu mujer lo interpretó como una de respuesta afirmativa:

> ¿Os interesa que me quite la camiseta? `Sí, nos interesa, quítatela`.

El DPD dice que *[importar](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=importar)* significa "tener interés para alguien o suponerle preocupación", que también son dos casos diferentes, aunque introduce una nueva acepción: "suponer preocupación", que sería la pregunta a la que se da respuesta habitualmente:

> ¿Os supone preocupación que abra la ventana? `No, preocupación ninguna, ábrela.`

En esta acepción nos basamos para dar respuesta a la pregunta de si nos importa o no, y es la que aplicamos al hacer la pregunta.

Mi teoría en cuanto a la "inversión" del significado de *importar* es que cuando alguien pregunta "¿os importa que abra la ventana?" en realidad lo que está preguntando, según el sentido original de *importar*, es "¿os importa (es importante para vosotros) que la ventana esté cerrada?".

Así, las preguntas en realidad deberían ser:

> ¿Es importante que a Juan no se le invite? `Si no, le invito.`
>   ¿Es importante que la última aceituna se quede en el plato? `Si no, me la como yo.`
>   ¿Es importante que me deje la camiseta puesta? `Si no, me la quito.`

Es decir, se debería preguntar si importa (es importante) mantener la inercia actual, para no hacer algo que perturbe una situación en la que nadie parece estar a disgusto. Cualquier cosa que rompa esa inercia supone pedir permiso. Imagino entonces que las frases "os importa (es importante) que me deje la camiseta puesta" y "puedo quitarme la camiseta" se fusionaron en "os importa que me quite la camiseta", con las respuestas esperadas como si se hubiese formulado la primera, aunque esto pueda llevar a respuestas de doble sentido. Si alguien responde que "sí" se puede interpretar como "sí es importante mantener la inercia actual", aunque también como "sí es importante (quiero) que te quites la camiseta".

Comment: @walen he intentado dar respuesta a tus preguntas, ampliando un poco con información encontrada en el DPD. Si aún así crees que no he respondido es que no he entendido bien la pregunta, y te pido disculpas por ello, al tiempo que te pediría también que me explicaras un poco mejor cuál es tu duda concreta.

Comment: @walen se me ocurrió como teoría que el sentido negativo de "importar" se viera influenciado por "importunar": "¿os importuna que abra la ventana?". Pero de momento no he encontrado pruebas.